# How to convert xlsb to xlsx using Azure Function?

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-linux

I've developed and successfully tested locally a function that converts xlsb files to xlsx. Once I tried to deploy and run on Azure Portal, I got the following failure `Result: Failure Exception: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'TEST.xlsx'` So I tried to research and read that due to Azure Function Python being linux based, files could only be saved to temp directory. I tried to modify my function to include temp directory but I get new error `Result: Failure Exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/TEST.xlsb'`. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this result: blob triggered azure function that converts xlsb file (in blob container) to xlsx and saves in blob container? Below are my first attempt and subsequent changes with the temp directory discovery:

```
import os
import logging
import pandas as pd
#from io import BytesIO
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient, BlobClient
 
app = func.FunctionApp()
 
@app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path="{containerName}/{name}.xlsb",
                               connection="BlobStorageConnectionString")
def blob_trigger(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob"
                f"Name: {myblob.name}"
                f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
   
    accountName = "name"
    accountKey = "key"
    connectionString = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={accountName};AccountKey={accountKey};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
   
    containerName = "{containerName}"
    inputBlobname = myblob.name.replace({containerName}, "")
    outputBlobname = inputBlobname.replace(".xlsb", ".xlsx")
 
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connectionString)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(containerName)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(inputBlobname)
    blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connectionString, container_name=containerName, blob_name=outputBlobname)
 
    df = pd.read_excel(blob_client.download_blob().readall(), engine="pyxlsb")
 
    df.to_excel(outputBlobname, index=False)
 
    with open(outputBlobname, "rb") as data:
        blob.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)
```

```
import os
import logging
import pandas as pd
#from io import BytesIO
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient, BlobClient

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path="{containerName}/{name}.xlsb",
                               connection="BlobStorageConnectionString") 
def blob_trigger(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob"
                f"Name: {myblob.name}"
                f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    
    accountName = "name"
    accountKey = "key"
    connectionString = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={accountName};AccountKey={accountKey};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    
    containerName = "{containerName}"
    inputBlobname = myblob.name.replace({containerName}, "")
    localBlobname = "/tmp/" + inputBlobname
    outputBlobname = inputBlobname.replace(".xlsb", ".xlsx")

    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connectionString)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(containerName)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(inputBlobname)
    blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connectionString, container_name=containerName, blob_name=outputBlobname)

    df = pd.read_excel(blob_client.download_blob().readall(), engine="pyxlsb")

    df.to_excel("/tmp/" + outputBlobname, index=False)
    ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))

    with open(file = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, localBlobname), mode="rb") as data:
        blob.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I tried the following code to convert a **.xlsb** blob to a **.xlsx** blob in an Azure storage container using the Azure Function app.*

**Code :**

```py
import logging
import pandas as pd
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from io import BytesIO

app = func.FunctionApp()
@app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path="<container_name>/<file_name>.xlsb",
                   connection="kamblobstr_STORAGE")
def blob_trigger(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")

    accountName = "<storage_name>"
    accountKey = "<strorage_key>"
    connectionString = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={accountName};AccountKey={accountKey};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"

    containerName = "<container_name>"
    outputBlobname = "<file_name>.xlsx"  

    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connectionString)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(containerName)

    input_data = myblob.read()
    df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(input_data), engine="pyxlsb")

    output_data = BytesIO()
    df.to_excel(output_data, index=False)
    output_data.seek(0)

    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(outputBlobname)
    blob_client.upload_blob(output_data.getvalue(), overwrite=True)
```

***local.settings.json :***

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storage_connec_string>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "kamblobstr_STORAGE": "<storage_connec_string>"
  }
}
```

**Output :**

The blob trigger function code is running, and I uploaded the **kamb.xlsb** file to the Azure blob storage container as shown below:

[image]

I received the message output: "blob **kamb.xlsb** converted to **kamb.xlsx**" as shown below:

```py
 *  Executing task: .venv\Scripts\activate && func host start 

Found Python version 3.10.11 (py).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5030 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.15.2.20177

[2024-03-17T04:00:10.684Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000xxxxxxxxxxxx'.
[2024-03-17T04:00:22.921Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        blob_trigger: blobTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-03-17T04:00:43.865Z] Executing 'Functions.blob_trigger' (Reason='New blob detected(LogsAndContainerScan): kamcontainer/kamb.xlsb', Id=4c9d45e5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
[2024-03-17T04:00:43.870Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: a1416e18xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, DequeueCount: 1, InsertedOn: 2024-03-17T04:00:43.000+00:00, BlobCreated: 2024-03-17T04:00:39.000+00:00, BlobLastModified: 2024-03-17T04:00:39.000+00:00
[2024-03-17T04:00:44.005Z] Python blob trigger function processed blobBlob Size: None bytes
[2024-03-17T04:00:47.081Z] Request URL: 'https://kamblobstr.blob.core.windows.net/kamcontainer/kamb.xlsx'
Request method: 'PUT'
Request headers:
    'Content-Length': '4976'
    'x-ms-blob-type': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
    'Accept': 'application/xml'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.19.1 Python/3.10.11 (Windows-10-10.0.22631-SP0)'
    'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': 'ef51c49exxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    'Authorization': 'REDACTED'
A body is sent with the request
[2024-03-17T04:00:49.113Z] Response status: 201
Response headers:
    'Content-Length': '0'
    'Content-MD5': 'REDACTED'
    'Last-Modified': 'Sun, 17 Mar 2024 04:00:49 GMT'
    'ETag': '"0x8DC4636D53FDEE9"'
    'Server': 'Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
    'x-ms-request-id': '94236a36xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': 'ef51c49exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-content-crc64': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-request-server-encrypted': 'REDACTED'
    'Date': 'Sun, 17 Mar 2024 04:00:49 GMT'
[2024-03-17T04:00:49.167Z] Executed 'Functions.blob_trigger' (Succeeded, Id=4c9d45e5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, Duration=6129ms)
```

[image]
[image]

Afterward, I successfully deployed my project to the Azure function app, as shown below:

[image]

I uploaded the **kamb.xlsb** file to the Azure blob storage container, and it ran successfully in the Function app on the Azure Portal, as shown below:

[image]

*The blob **kamb.xlsb** was converted to **kamb.xlsx** in the storage container, as shown below.*

[image]

**kamb.xlsx data :**

[image]

**Function app Monitor Logs :**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! May I ask what configurations must be changed if my storage account does not have public network access available? I was testing successfully with a public storage account, but I need to use the private one. I get new error "The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found."